# Rspec not work post :create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails

There are models Users, Ad and Orders.The relationship they are.When testing gives an error that the object is not created.I think that the path was not created correctly

```
expected `Order.count` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  has_many :ads
  has_many :orders, through: :ads
end
```

**Ad.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :orders
```

**Orders.rb**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ad
end
```

**Controller create**

```
def create
  @order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)

  if @order.save
    render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order
  else
    render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

**Rspec test**

```
it 'create a new Order' do
    request.cookies[JWTSessions.access_cookie] = @tokens[:access]
    request.headers[JWTSessions.csrf_header] = @tokens[:csrf]
    expect do
      post :create, params: { order: valid_attributes}
    end.to change(Order, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: check the logs, maybe the request is not even reaching the action if cookies and headers are not valid, maybe valid_attributes doesn't actually have valid attributes. Personally, I would put a "order.valid?; puts order.errors.inspect" on the controller to print something in the console if the order is invalid, be sure that the request is reaching the create action, and be sure that the order object is really valid to be saved

Comment: I agree with @arieljuod, I wold first test if you model is able to save or create the record with the attributes you are sending. 
My second thought is that probably your request (POST) is not being saved and you have to inspect your @order.errors. You can try a ``puts  @orders.errors.inspect`` in order to see if there are validations messages' errors